# Is a PHP-function in an unprotected file vulnerable?

Tags: php, security

I'm developing a PHP-application and have a PHP file with some utility functions. For example `utils.php`:

```php
function tidyUpDatabase(){
   //do some stuff 
}

function logoutUser(){
   //do some stuff 
}
```

This utility file is thought for including in other PHP-scripts that call theese functions. But of course it can be also requested directly via the webserver (e.g. `https://localhost/app1/utils/utils.php`) which will deliver an empty page. Is that workflow vulnerable in some cases? Can someone call the functions inside the utils file over the webserver...?

Comment: `Can someone call` - yes, someone can (e.g. some Web Crawler that finds link in your page). You **must** add authentication/authorization, otherwise anyone can mess up with your server

Comment: NO, a file that contain only function definitions is 100% harmless no matter what

Comment: @Justinas Of course someone can call the file! But can he also execute a function in that file?

Comment: to execute a function one must call it, and function cannot be executed directly from url until you map them to request like `if($_GET['a'] == 'a'){ call_function() }` etc.

Comment: On other hand you can call js function from browser console by window.functionName() and it will execute right away if the function is declared globally like you did above in Php.

Comment: @stillKonfuzed I know about that for javascript... But i was talking about PHP code that is executed on the server

Comment: No, it is 100% safe for php. @superjojo140

Comment: @superjojo140 If there is no method calls, then it's ok. But configure your setup so that source code is not accessible via url and only `public/index.php` that handles routing.

Comment: If you don't want your PHP file accessible to public you can put it outside of the web root. It can still be included in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that a PHP file that is in the public folder can be called (unless protected by the attributes).  But if it only has functions then they can not be executed.  However, if you have code in there, outside the function that calls the function, then it may get executed.

The usual thing to do is to put your function files in a folder such as **/lib**.  And then protect the folder so that it can not be read or executed.  You can do this with a combination of access rights and **.htaccess** file if you are using something like **apache**.